How do I calculate sum per frame?
I'm trying to find a way to control the rotation speed of an object. First I tried rotating it using a driver and then multiplying that driver with a control value that ranges between 0 (standing still) and 1 (full speed), and then animating that value. This doesn't work because the driver keeps increasing the overall rotation even for frames when the object is standing still.
For example, if the driver is #frame*C, where $C$ is a rotation per frame constant, the object rotation on frame 100 is 100C, no matter if the object has only been rotating for 10 frames.
After some thinking I figured out that the overall rotation in each frame needs to be a sum per frame of a rotation per frame constant and the control value in that specific frame. If that sounds confusing, the formula looks like this: $R(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n C*x(i)$
$R(n)$ is the object rotation on frame $n$.
$C$ is the rotation per frame constant.
$x(i)$ is the control value on a specific frame.
If $x=0$, the object is standing still, if $x=1$, the object is rotating at full speed. When $x$ is increasing, the object rotation is speeding up. When $x$ is decreasing, the object rotation is slowing down.
A frame where $x=0$ adds $0$ to object rotation.
A frame where $x=0.5$ adds $C/2$ to object rotation.
A frame where $x=1$ adds $C$ to object rotation.
And I know that my formula doesn't look standard, but I've been out of university for 4 years and this is the first time I had to use calculus since then.
The math behind this problem is already solved, but I need to find a way to translate it into a form blender can work with, while still being able to animate (keyframe) the control value $x$.
The problem is that I don't know any coding so I don't know how to make this formula work in blender or where to input it.

you first should tell exactly how your rotation should look like. Constant? accelerating? or...?

I already described that in the question - a constant multiplied by a value I can animate.

no you didn't. you wrote "first i tried...." you didn't write "i want ..." so you should make that clear, sorry.

"After some thinking I figured out that the overall rotation in each frame needs to be a sum per frame of a rotation per frame constant and the control value in that specific frame." it is there. maybe try reading the whole question before offering unhelpful and obnoxious answers.

Could you perhaps show some images of what you have and what you try to achieve? This is hard to follow as it is.

Hi, @Lynx095, I think we could clear this up with a very simple statement, (If I'm right,)  that you're looking to make  a speed dX controller, rather than  a  value X controller, in this case, for rotation. I think this takes you into what Blender considers 'simulation' territory.. ordinary drivers don't have a memory. One way or another, a value at frame f-1 has to be fed into the calculation at frame f. GN Simulation might be one approach. If I am on the right track, then a quick edit will re-open.

Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you.

@StefLAncien Thank you very much. It works perfectly for me. I tried recreating it before I noticed that you added a file here, and I used only 1 group input node. Will that make a difference?
Also, I don't need this for myself, I'm helping another artist in the polygoniq discord server, who didn't know the math nor the node setup for this, and I'm still waiting to hear back from him.

You are welcome. There is no restriction on how many Group Input nodes you add. So I am usually trying to limit overlong or tangled "noodles" by adding more than one. It is also convenient with Crt+h to limit the view to only connected sockets, for example here to have in the blue one, only $C$ and $x(i)$ that are related parameters.

@StefLAncien the artist I was helping is satisfied too and sends his thanks as well. I'm thinking of giving it some additional functionality (option to rotate independently on each axis, a switch for clockwise and counter-clockwise rotation, an rpm to rotation per frame converter node, maybe more), and putting in on the blender market for a small price. Is that okay with you?

(Using Blender 3.6.8)
Approach
This proposal relies on a GeometryNodes modifier attached to the rotating object. The rotation per frame constant $C$ is a user-defined input. The control value per frame $x(i)$ is an animated property, controlled by key-frames and key-values.

This figure illustrates a setup where a cube is rotating with $C=1$ degree/frame. $x(i)=0$ from frames 0 to 9. So at frame 9, its rotation is still 0 degrees. Then $x(i)=0.5$ from frames 10 to 19. So at frame 19, its rotation is 5 degrees. Then $x(i)=1$ from frames 20 to 29. So at frame 29, its rotation is 15 degrees (5+10). Then $x(i)=0$ from frames 30 to 39. So its rotation remains 15 degrees. Eventually $x(i)=-0.5$ from frames 40 to 69. So its rotation decreases by -0.5 degrees/frame until it reaches 0 degree at frame 69, in 30 frames.
GeometryNodes graph

1. The instantaneous rotation $R(n)$ is summed in a Simulation Zone.
2. $R(0)$ is initialized at 0 in the Simulation Input node.
3. For each frame, $R(n)$ is updated as $R(n+1)=C\times x(n) + R(n)$ using a Multiply Add math node.
4. $R(n+1)$ is "exposed" through the Simulation Output node, in particular for the next frame.
5. At every frame, "downstream" the Simulation Zone, the current value of $R(n)$ is combined in a vector input in a Transform Geometry node to rotate the object vertices around its origin (NB: A vector connected to the "Rotation" socket must be in radians, whatever the angular unit selected).
6. The remaining dark red part of the graph is to display the value of $R(n)$ for the demonstration.
Resources:

